# Find and replace <?php & ?> in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large string of valid HTML code that will be inserted into the DOM, the string also contains PHP code. I want the php code to be displayed as plain text, Chrome automatically comments out the PHP code. Obviously the PHP code is wrapped in `<?php ... ?>` so my question is:

How can I replace the open `<?php` with a `<span>` tag, and replace the `?>` with a `</span>` to close the open `<span>` tag so that the PHP code is within the `<span>` tags and therefor visible as plain text?

EDIT: I will be wrapping the PHP code back in `<?php ?>` by replacing the span, so escaping the  characters will make that more difficult.

Comment: Do you want to simply escape it so that it all shows?

Comment: I will be converting the span back to <?php ?> by getting the text in the span tag, so I guess not.

Comment: Use [`htmlentities()`](https://3v4l.org/t2Jhr) on your PHP content (as string), which will give you characters that are interpreted as string in the browser.

Comment: Hold on, is what you're trying to do is get the PHP code between delimiters (as string)?

Answer (score 1):

You could escape it.

From:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say that the HTML is a string, you can easily just use the `replace()` function.

```
var html = // your html
var sanitized = html.replace(/<\?php/g, "<span>").replace(/\?>/g, "</span>");
```

Comment: needs more regex

Comment: @DZDomi fixed it

Comment: thanks. much better now. You have some spare time to talk about jesus, our lord and saviour?

Comment: @DZDomi yes always

Comment: I don't think you can have quotes around your regexp

Answer (score 0):

Use **Regular Expressions!**

[RegExp101](https://regex101.com/) is a great playground. 
Remember to change the flavor on the left menu to *JavaScript*.

The easiest way is using the `.replace()` function.

`var str = str.replace(/(<\?php)|(<\?)|(<\?=)/g, '<span>').replace(/(\?>)/g, '</span>');`

**Edit:** As requested by [Get Off My Lawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1778465/get-off-my-lawn), I've added support to `<?=` nd `<?` tags. The pipe `|` represents an **or** in Regular Expressions.

Comment: might also want to support `<?`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm not a PHP guy, is `<?` without the `php` a thing? If so, would it work as an alternate opening tag (I can easily add it to the solution)

Comment: Yeah it is a thing. php supports multiple items: `<?php`, `<?` and `<?=`

Comment: as of php v7: `The ASP tags <%, %>, <%=, and the script tag <script language="php"> are removed from PHP.`

Comment: You could also simplify it to this: `str.replace(/<(\?(php|=)|%)?/ig, '<span>').replace(/(\?|%)>/ig, '</span>')`